# How do I authorize a facebook application? PHP

Tags: facebook, graph, oauth, facebook-oauth

I have a php web app set up to handle my new facebook application. I am looking at my app at http://apps.facebook.com/myapp and it shows my app in an iframe.

I am trying to get the app to bring up the screen where it requests permission. I can't seem to find a anything that explains the flow. I don't have an issue reading profile details once I create the $fb->loginUrl() link and click through to it, but I want a permission request to load automatically when you go first to the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iFrame App. Permissions Request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436496/iframe-app-permissions-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code - It is working code that I use when I create application. I assume from your message that you use PHP SDK

```
< ?php
    require_once('facebook.php');
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR APP ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR APP SECRET',
  'cookie' => true
));
if ($user = $facebook->getUser()) { //user is logged in and authorized us
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
    print "Welcome User ID: " . $user;
    print_r($fbme);

} else { // User has not authorized us or is not logged in
    $params = array(
        'fbconnect'=>0,
                'canvas'=>1,
        'req_perms'=>'publish_stream,email',
    // For a full list of permissions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions
    );
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
     print "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
}
```

Don't forget to test it on new and fresh browser and other account.

Comment: Look at the answer of @yannick-richard - he is absolutely right. You should correct your code snippet a little.

Answer (score 3):

with new php sdk getSessions() isn't working anymore,  should use it like this `:

if ($user = $facebook->getUser()) { //user is logged in and authorized us