# Facebook Extended permissions in canvas via php

Tags: php, facebook, api, canvas

I'm working on my new project, Woobook. I used the Old REST API until now but i should learn to work with latest one (with OAuth). First i want to get extended permissions but the attached code redirect me to a wrong page (instead of permissions dialog directly).

My app link: http://apps.facebook.com/woobook/

and the source code:

```
<?php
// Facebook API inc
require_once "inc/facebook.php";

// API init
$cid = "162513840463126";
$asi = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $cid,
  'secret' => $asi,
  'cookie' => true,
));
// Session
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if(!$facebook->getUser()) {
        header("Location:".$facebook->getLoginUrl(array("next" => "http://apps.facebook.com/woobook/", "canvas" => 1, "req_perms" => "user_status,publish_stream,user_photos"))."");
        exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an iframe app, which means you need to do this a little differently.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436496)

Comment: Thank you buddy :) Can you tell my how can i check the permissions ?

Comment: Should probably make that a separate question, although I imagine you can discover the answer with a little searching.