# Processing response after Facebook login with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook

I have built a canvas game for FB and I now want to allow users to log into it using their Facebook account.

I am testing with my own account (which is the administrator account for the app, which still isn't available to the public). Using the following code to create the URL for the authorization dialog if the user hasn't authorized the app already:

```
$data['fb_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope'=>'email, user_friends',
                'redirect_uri'=>'https://apps.facebook.com/appname/',
                'display'=>'page'
            ));
```

This redirects fine, and shows the authorization dialog. However, after I click 'play now' on the dialog there's a problem. Even though the app is added to my app center, I can't access it. It redirects to the URL I provided (which is the app page on FB) but it then redirects back to the authorization page. This redirect is only supposed to happen if the user hasn't authorized the app yet.

On the page, I use the native SDK function to get the ID of the logged in FB user:

```
$userId = $this->facebook->getUser();
```

However, this returns 0 so the endless redirect loop continues.

This is the exact URL that the authorization redirects to:

```
https://apps.facebook.com/appname/?code=AQCwk7n6AljygSC1ekxJKFqJjAZF6PyCFECzgaYciAQIJWt10o7LatWSlMUkAqiesI2MHAh4zWAxcCgWP1-WpF19H8qb6CNUKS11-rrbN4un02QkT6_P8KcHVVfD-0ppUkbrPjWopB1TbKABO0SlZESJEpFOAKdOUUr0LoLoIcYgJ_7FA4MaVcSQs438QzmZGudPeDRskSWtc6dy0-PmUUHPEYxcjPRyUUDG5VbVruIUwsX6Lco4Qi55K-kaNiHZrEOkbpo8UUhEGF5MfrbssNJqgQ5sz-fq-hvCoy9ppTsx6wo0N-cXAUWnBCGOmn0IWE4&state=e2bda7a95d2e2cfb7b104c83defda0e4#_=_
```

Comment: are you using safari browser ? have you started the sessions in php ? please try showing the full script for login ..

Comment: No and yes, in that order. I am moving on to SDK4 at the moment, will update this thread when I try it.

Comment: Are you running on codeigniter by any chance?

Comment: @madebydavid Yes I am. Any input based on that?

Comment: @jovan, sorry for the delay - please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();
```

will always return 0 , unless the user has authorized your application 
 insted you can get the  `getloginurl()`

```
if(empty($_GET['code'])
{
  //show login url
}
```

Change the redirect uri to your website

Comment: I don't understand. The code is already `$userId = ...`; if($userId==0){ //getLoginUrl etc} else{ //display app }. Doesn't `empty($_GET['code'])` amount to the same as `$userId==0`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `$this->facebook->getUser();` 
Do you have the latest version? It's [Version 4](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0), and the sample code I see there is different from the one you're using, which, by the way, reminds me of an older version.
Their code to get the current user, as stated in the README file of the [Github Repository](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) is as follows:

```
  $me = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'GET', '/me'
  ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
  echo $me->getName();
```

I am uncertain of whether that's the problem, because I use no libraries for Facebook. I thought it could be useful though to link to the new version of the library. I don't think the empty variable is the problem, because the old library, as far as I remember, didn't check the presence the code variable, but used to check if you had a logged in user, and maybe the part of the programming checking if you had a variable in the URL was in the login function (I may be wrong, because the last time I read code from the Facebook library was a couple of years ago). Also, if that were the problem, it shouldn't work at all, but the first redirection is fine. There is a problem with getting the user, I'd say.

**EDIT**
While browsing for related problems with an accepted solution, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763131/facebook-extended-permissions-in-canvas-via-php?rq=1). Could it be the `$this` pseudovariable, that didn't convince me when I saw it, the problem of your result whe you try to get the user, irrespective of the library you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You're using CodeIgniter which deletes `$_REQUEST` which is used by the Facebook PHP SDK to retrieve the OAuth code param.

The trick is to copy `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` before your call to `$facebook->getUser()`:

```
$_REQUEST += $_GET; 
$userId = $this->facebook->getUser();
```

Alternatively, don't use CodeIgniter or use a version of the FB SDK which has been adapted to work with CI.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you you are missing one point. When you are using PHP backend script for connecting to facebook API, you are not using same session for connection to Facebook as it's already in your browser.

Practically you would have to make a new connection in backend and authorize there on FB, but that is not something you would like to have.

To solve this issue, when you authorize user in browser, take the Token that is returned to you from API. With that token you can make any authorized request on users' account.

Basically the only problem that you have is problem with sessions (as far as I can see).